# Magento 2 - How to allow livereload in CSP whitelist?

Tags: magento2, livereload, csp

I can't use livereload anymore, because I get

> Refused to load the script 'http://www.company.de:35729/livereload.js' because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive ... Note that
> 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a
> fallback."

Im not sure why I get this error even though the script is hosted on my own server.

I tried to allow it like this in my

**app\code\Company\Csp\etc\csp_whitelist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <values>
                <value id="livereload" type="host">www.company.de*</value>
                ...
```

But it does not work this way.

---

**Notes**:

```
<?php

namespace Company\Csp\Plugin;   // <-- in my real script, Company is replaced by my vendor name

use Magento\Csp\Model\Collector\CspWhitelistXmlCollector;
use Magento\Csp\Model\Policy\FetchPolicy;

class Csp
{

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function afterCollect(CspWhitelistXmlCollector $cspWhitelistXmlCollector, $defaultPolicies = []): array
    {
        $ip = dns_get_record($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],DNS_A)[0]['ip'];
        $port = "35729";
        $hostUrl = $ip . ':' . $port;

        $defaultPolicies[] = new FetchPolicy(
            "connect-src",
            false,
            [$hostUrl, "ws://" . $hostUrl],
            [],
            false,
            false,
            false,
            [],
            [],
            false,
            false
        );
        $defaultPolicies[] = new FetchPolicy(
            "script-src",
            false,
            [$hostUrl],
            [],
            false,
            false,
            false,
            [],
            [],
            false,
            false
        );
        return $defaultPolicies;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this extension:

https://github.com/ghostunicorns/module-csp-livereload

How to install:

`composer require ghostunicorns/module-csp-livereload`

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and fixed it with the following:

**Create a plugin**

app/code/Company/Csp/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Csp\Model\Collector\CspWhitelistXmlCollector">
        <plugin name="cspAddLivereload" type="MyCompany\Csp\Plugin\Csp" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Company/Csp/Plugin/Csp.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Csp\Plugin;

use Magento\Csp\Model\Collector\CspWhitelistXmlCollector;
use Magento\Csp\Model\Policy\FetchPolicy;

class Csp
{

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function afterCollect(CspWhitelistXmlCollector $cspWhitelistXmlCollector, $defaultPolicies = []): array
    {
        $defaultPolicies[] = new FetchPolicy(
            "connect-src",
            false,
            ["www.company.de:35729", "ws://www.company.de:35729"],
            [],
            false,
            false,
            false,
            [],
            [],
            false,
            false
        );
        $defaultPolicies[] = new FetchPolicy(
            "script-src",
            false,
            ["www.company.de:35729"],
            [],
            false,
            false,
            false,
            [],
            [],
            false,
            false
        );
        return $defaultPolicies;
    }
}
```

This adds the specified policies to the Csp programmatically.

I have changed some things to work with your URL, so it's not fully tested

Comment: Does not work unfortunatelly. I still get the error. I changed `company` to my own vendor/domain everywhere of course.

Comment: Have you tried running bin/magento setup:di:compile and ensured that the module is enabled?

Comment: Your URL should appear in the CSP in the headers of the HTML page. Chrome dev console -> Network Tab -> your html page -> Headers -> Content-Security-Policy

Comment: The module is enabled and compiled. There is no  `content-security-policy` there is only `content-security-policy-reporty-only` in "Response Headers"

Comment: The cache should also be cleaned if you haven't already. If that doesn't help, then please check if the Plugin is loaded. Possibly adding `die;` somewhere in the afterCollect() function (if you are on a dev environment). If that doesn't do anything, the Plugin may not be loaded correctly

Comment: I cleared the cache. I added `die('csp test')` to the first line in the afterCollect method and it died with the message. So the plugin gets loaded, but it still throws the error message about the CSP violation in the browser console.

Comment: Then I think the URLs may not be correct. In my case, I have to use the IP address to get LiveReload to work with `grunt watch`. I used the following to get my ip automatically

`$ip = dns_get_record($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],DNS_A)[0]['ip'];`
`$hostUrl = $ip . ':35729';`

Does the error stay the same if you enable run `grunt watch` in your shell environment?

Comment: I tried it, please look at my updated question. I added my afterCollect method. Of course I tried it with `grunt watch`, but it still throws the same error.

Comment: Are you loading the livereload.js through `$hostUrl`/livereload.js? If you are and it doesn't work, please check the content-security-policy-report-only or content-security-policy if that contains your `$hostUrl`.

Comment: I checked *content-security-policy-report-only*, this is what it shows (i replaced the real IP with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): `script-src ... xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:35729 ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:35729 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';` and ` `connect-src  ... xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:35729 ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:35729 'self' 'unsafe-inline';` I am loading the livereload.js like this `<script src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:35729/livereload.js" src_type="url"></script>`

Comment: Strange, you have everything the same as me, except that you have `content-security-policy-report-only`. I have the non report-only `content-security-policy`

Comment: I will just disable the Magento_Csp module and enable it again if it is fully developed.

Comment: Have you tried accessing your site through http instead of https? I seem to have this issue as well if I connect to my site with https

Comment: I allowed mixed content already in chrome website settings, so thats not the problem.

Comment: Allowing mixed content on my site does not fix that issue for me, so I think it's worth a try to access your site through `http://www.company.de`

Answer (score 1):

Create **csp_whitelist.xml** path: app/code/Sample/Module/etc/csp_whitelist.xml
If your livereload connects to ws://127.0.0.1:35729/livereload it should be this:

```
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="connect-src">
            <values>
                <value id="livereload" type="host">ws://127.0.0.1:35729/livereload</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```